# Trying to print 10 lines of 100 array values in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, printf

I have an array with 100 numbers in it, and I am trying to print it out with only 10 ints on each line, and a tab between each number. It is only printing the first 10 integers and then stopping, which makes sense because of my for loop. I am clearly missing part of it to allow for it to continue through the array. I was going to try to add the line

```
for(int line_num = 0; line_num < 10; line_num+=10)
```

before the for statement after the while loop

```
int array_value;
int length_of_array = 100;

while (length_of_array <= 100){
    for(array_value = 0; array_value < 10; ++array_value){
        printf("%d  ", A[array_value]);
        ++length_of_array;      
    }
```

I was also thinking of including a line like

```
if (array_value % 10 == 0)
            printf("\n");
```

I figured it out! Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
/* test.c  */

#include <stdio.h>

#define ELEMENTS    100 

int main (void)
{
    int array [ELEMENTS];

    for ( int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i )
        array [i] = i;

    for ( int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i ) {
        printf ("%i", array[i]);
        if ( (i + 1) % 10 != 0 )
            printf ("\t");
        else
            printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

edit: Because of the way the tab can extend to the next line at the end of the line you have to be careful with the tab and new line character.

Comment: This helped a ton!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, rename length_of_array to offset_in_array and then set it to zero at the start. I renamed array_value and corrected your length check.  I also added a check to the inner loop in case the array length gets changed and doesn't divide by 10.
Something like:

```
int i;
#define ARRAY_LENGTH 100
int offset_in_array = 0;

while (offset_in_array < ARRAY_LENGTH){
    for(i = 0; i < 10 && offset_in_array < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i){
        printf("%d  ", A[offset_in_array]);
        ++offset_in_array;      
    }
}
```

I haven't tried running this but it should be closer.

Comment: Thanks for working on that! It didn't end up printing only 10 integers per line, it has the same output as my original code but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just print a newline every tenth number... If it's not a tenth number, then print a tab.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
    printf("%d%c", A[i], i % 10 != 9 ? '\t' : '\n');
}
```

Live code available at [onlinedbg](https://onlinegdb.com/SkfvGQd9X).

Answer (score 1):

Just change the value of `length_of_array` to `0` and print `\n` after a `for` loop.

```
int array_value;
int length_of_array = 0;

while (length_of_array <= 100) {
    for(array_value = 0; array_value < 10; ++array_value){
        printf("%d  ", A[array_value]);
        ++length_of_array;      
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to print 10 lines of 100 array values in C:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
    printf("%i\t", A[i]);
    if ((i+1)%10 == 0){
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I made a small change to my answer above as it may affect how the list of numbers are displayed at the end of each line.

Comment: A code only answer is not so informative.  Better to comment or describe how this code solved this question.  The `'\t'` before the  `'\n'` is a source of surprises and errors.  I do not recommend this solution as it   adds tabs outside of "10 ints on each line, and a tab between each number".

Comment: @chux: oddly enough the code had already been edited with regard to the tab and new line characters before you posted your comment.